# unix fork command can return only one child?

Tags: unix, process, fork

Im sorry for such a noobie question but Im not familiar with Unix(system calls). Im trying to understand the fork command and I know fork command returns pid 0 if its child process or returns pid for child id. I want to know a process can have only one child at a time and returns its pid or can have multiple child processes?( actually I cant imagine if it has more than one child, how to return pid and which pid?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29) is not a Unix *command*, but a [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) documented in the [fork(2)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) Posix man page. The Linux man page is [fork(2) -linux-](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html) here.

On success, the `fork` syscall returns twice: once in the (calling) parent process (where it gives the `pid` of the child process), and once in the newly created child process (where it gives 0). Otherwise, the two process are clones (and some Linux implementations have a `fork` implemented above the Linux specific [clone(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clone.2.html) syscall) and are executing the same program with nearly the same state (actually two nearly identical copies). The two (parent and child) processes are running simultaneously (as tasks scheduled by the kernel, perhaps in parallel on different processor cores).

The `fork(2)` syscall might (rarely) fail (e.g. to avoid [fork bombs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)), e.g. when the `RLIMIT_NPROC` limit set with [setrlimit(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) syscall has been reached. When it does fail, the `fork` syscall return -1 and you should check `errno`. It is good practice to check the failure of every syscall, and `fork` is not an exception.

Fork is the usual way to start processes, all [but some rare exceptions] the user processes are started by some `fork` syscall (or a variant like `vfork(2)`, or `clone(2)`). In particular, when you type a command (e.g. `ls` or `date`) in a shell (e.g. `/bin/bash` perhaps running in a terminal emulator), the shell is very often `fork`-ing itself, then `execve`-ing the required program (exceptions are shell builtins like `cd`).

<sup>Notice that nearly all processes on a Linux system have been created by `fork`. The exceptions are kernel-started processes like `/sbin/init` or `/sbin/modprobe` ...</sup>

You can call `fork` many times (a typical shell implementation does that for every command, except the builtin ones like `cd`; you might want to study the source code of free software shells like `sash` or `bash`). You should eventually wait for the child processes using the [wait(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/wait.2.html) or `waitpid(2)` syscall. A process can change its executable file and address space with the [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall. Its [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) can change using [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and related syscalls.

You might want to use `strace -f` to understand what syscalls are made, e.g. by some shell.

I strongly recommend reading the [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup/) book and the [Advanced Linux programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com) book (the later being available on line with some free license).

Comment: After reading twice I dont understand the usage of fork. If we have only two identical copy of a process and one can be used at a time, why dont we use the parent for what we want to do? Why do we copy the same process?

Comment: Because `fork` is the *only way* to create new processes. (There are some weird rare exceptions, but you can ignore them at first). On most Unix systems, all processes are descendants of the `/sbin/init` process of pid 1 and have been started by `fork`

Comment: Cant I execute what I want in parent process?(sorry if the questions are so basic...)

Comment: Yes, you can do what you want in both parent and in child process. You usually have to set up shared resources (like `pipe(2)`) before the fork. You'll better eventually `wait` the child in the parent (or you may get *zombie processes* mentioned in Joachim's answer. **Please read the references** that I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

*Each call* to [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) creates a single child process and only returns that single process' PID, but there is nothing preventing you from calling `fork()` multiple times to create multiple child processes.

Don't forget to [wait() or waitpid()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html) for your forked child processes to exit, or you may get [zombie processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) hanging around.

Comment: Than if I call fork multiple times one ofter another, for creating new child should parent process wait for the child process to finish?

Comment: @KaaN You may fork() any number of child processes, and yes, you should wait for them to exit or they'll keep hanging around. You can do it blocking or non blocking, so you don't need to actually stop your parent process to wait.

Comment: thanks so much. If I dont misunderstand I should check if its parent or child process to create new one.

Comment: @KaaN If fork() returns anything != 0, you're in the parent process, if it returns 0, you're in the child. A bit confusing with a single call that returns twice, once in each process :) A parent needs to wait for its children to terminate, the children don't have to know anything about their parent. Remember to check for a return value < 0 in the parent for failure though, when memory gets low that may very well happen.

Comment: Could you look at the question below the Basil's answer that I asked too?

Answer (score 2):

Same answer as others with a twist: If each process could create only one child (use fork() only once), what would that mean for the *lineage* of processes? It would mean that there is exactly one line, say, `init -> login -> shell -> ls`. Would you like such a system? What is your conclusion?

Comment: I can only imagine that this simplifies the  usage of system...actually Isnt it running behind like your example

Comment: Well, it's a single user, single tasking system, in essence. Simple, yet not satisfactory in todays world...

Comment: Does it change on x64 systems then(is it related)? Or am I thinking too far from the subject

Comment: @KaaN: I think you are confused. What does 32/64 bit have to do with what/when/how fork returns? You can fork() as many times as you want, thus creating arbitrary trees of siblings.

Comment: I think so. I should read Basile's referances first. thanks for your answers appreciate it :)